# redux and performance hit if I pass all of the state each time on connect?

Tags: react-redux

I am curious if there is a performance hit with the following, in regards to Redux with React.

**Single Page App**

1. I have hundreds of components

   - Rather than being explicit about what part of the state tree I want. I hand back ALL of the state tree to each component that I connect with.

The State Tree encompasses many reducers with potentially hundreds of data points and shallow deep data structures.

So, for example. In my Shoe component, the props w/ state currently looks like:

```
class Shoe extends Component{}
// result of connect and my full load of redux state
// this will all grow as the applications grow
this.props.state => {
   shoes: {},
   cost: {},
   customer: {},
   bikes: {},
   cars: {},
   colors: {}, 
   geo: {}
}

BUT, this particular component only needs shoes:
this.props.state => {
   shoes: {}
}
```

Initially I figured, it is good that the component gets everything so I have at my disposal everything I "could" need. But as the application has grown and grown and grown, I am curious if there is a performance issue that could result of literally hundreds of components getting the full breadth of the state tree, rather than selected pieces. Of course, I reduce the possibility of mutation, but curious about performance here.

Comment: IMO - if you take the time to architect the state, it is pretty easy to extend, there is no need to do this. You will get an insane amount of props on each component with redux I don't think this is a great idea, it kind of sounds like you want to be lazy with passing props. Components should have their own api and stick to just that. This is just my opinion of course! I would assume you would take a performance hit but I'm sure someone can answer that much better than I.

Comment: when you say "no need to do this.." are you saying "passing everything down" or ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, why would you want 100 extra functions and objects in a component that's api calls for like 10-20 maybe? Just so you can have access to them at any point? If you architect your state upfront like redux docs mention you should never need this.

Comment: well, I have everything in proper order, I believe - I was just reducing noise by handing everything back so the component doesn't need to request certain parts of the state tree. For the actions, yeah - I explicitly ONLY request what I need on that I don't ask for everything there. But perhaps I should follow the same convention I do with "actions". I only give the component what it needs for that.

Comment: Yeah I will admit having worked with it for a bit it's a bit tedious, but it is manageable. I've been using redux multi-reducers - https://github.com/erikras/multireducer to split the "state" even further and been liking it a lot. Also one thing worth mentioning if a component gets new props it will re-render unless you use something like the pure render mixin, but I think react is saying not to use those mixins now. IMO it's much cleaner to just give the components what they need to work and no more, it simplifies the process lots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with Dan very briefly via messenger, and yes - there is a performance hit.

So, we want to limit the state we add onto the props, to that which you only need.

So, unless I hear anything different, I will assume that is the correct way to go.